# Issue with Outputing Variables in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing some basic java work for a Year 12 school course, and am struggling to find what i have wrong in this code. When num2 is larger than num1, the output is fine, but when num1 is larger than num2, im getting 3 outputs instead of two. I'm not sure if i've done something wrong with the brackets but im only just beginning to learn java and cant see the issue with this.

e.g if num1 is 3, and num2 is 2, I'm getting 2 , 3 , 2 as my outputs, but if num1 is 2 and num2 is 3, i'm getting 2,3 as my output

```
import java.util.*;

public class HigherNumber
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        Scanner scannum1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner scannum2 = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
        num1 = scannum1.nextInt();
        scannum1.close();

        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = scannum2.nextInt();
        scannum2.close();

        {
        if (num1 > num2) {
            System.out.println (num2);
            System.out.println (num1);
        }
        else
            System.out.println (num1);
            System.out.println (num2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
else      
 System.out.println (num1);
 System.out.println (num2);
```

needs an opening brace:

```
else {    
    System.out.println (num1);
    System.out.println (num2);
}
```

The code overall(since you're losing your braces everywhere) should read:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HigherNumber{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        Scanner scannum1 = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner scannum2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
        num1 = scannum1.nextInt();
        scannum1.close();
        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = scannum2.nextInt();
        scannum2.close();
        if (num1 > num2) {
            System.out.println (num2);
        System.out.println (num1);
        }
        else{    
            System.out.println (num1);
            System.out.println (num2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try that, i get
File: E:\HigherNumber.java  [line: 32]
Error: Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Comment: Also, there's an unusually placed opening brace before the `if`. Copy-paste error maybe?

Comment: @DennisMeng See edit. Herk: Your braces are everywhere. I fixed them up. Next time let your IDE handle braces and indentation for you.

Comment: Yup, that extra brace at the start was the issue, thanks, what do you mean by IDE?

Comment: @Herk An IDE is a program like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) that aid in writing code by offering syntax completions, suggestions of valid variables, methods, and classes, and other things like that. It's an all-in-one tool for writing, debugging, running, and designing code.

Comment: Ah ok, sadly our school uses a program called Dr Java and doesn't allow us to install any other programs :(

Comment: @Herk You should install Eclipse at home if you can as it's free and doesn't require administrator rights to install. Dr. Java is also an IDE albeit a less powerful one in my personal opinion.

Comment: Awesome, I'll start using that at home over Dr Java, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create two different Scanners - you can create one Scanner instance and call nextInt() two different times. Like this:

```
Scanner scannum1 = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
num1 = scannum1.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
num2 = scannum1.nextInt();
scannum1.close();
```